# read json, process file and write json back to disk in php

Tags: php, json

I want to read a json file in php. Process the string as a variable. Then output a nicely formatted json file to disk. But the echo output contains escape sequences, which I don't want. And the output file is completely blank! That shouldn't be. What can I do?

```
echo gives: "[\n { \n \"Class\": \"B\", \n \"Rating\": \"1600\", \n \"ID\": \"16733310\", \n \"Name\": \"Larrategui, Martin\", \n \"Expires\": \"\"\n }, ....etc. (This is not the nicely formatted json file I need.)

<?php 

$file = file_get_contents("uscf.json"); 
$new = strtolower($file);
$new = str_replace('1000.10.10','',$new);

$myJSON = json_encode($new);

echo ($myJSON); //output gives the code below (x300) instead of a nicely formatted json.

//"[\n { \n \"Class\": \"B\", \n \"Rating\": \"1600\", \n \"ID\": \"16733310\", \n \"Name\": \"Larrategui, Martin\", \n \"Expires\": \"\"\n }, ....etc.

$myfile = fopen("uscf_mems.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile,$myJSON); fclose($myfile); chmod($myfile,0777);
```

Comment: Replace `$myJSON = json_encode($new);` with `$myJSON = $new;`

Comment: absolutely fixed the formatting problem. But what about the write to disk issue?

Comment: Beats me. Turn on error reporting and check the file permissions. PHP should be yelling at you for something... Try [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: I deleted the file and then recreated it. php output worked fine.